# Alamofire.swift completionHandler Missing argument for parameter #2 in call

Tags: swift

I have two errors remaining and they are the same errors. Don't know what could be wrong. I even copy and pasted from the source Alamofire doc and made sure pods were up to date but same error.

```
public func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: ((NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void)) {
        if sessionDidReceiveChallenge != nil {
            completionHandler(sessionDidReceiveChallenge!(session, challenge)) // Missing argument for parameter #2 in call
        } else {
            completionHandler(.PerformDefaultHandling, nil)
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well from the looks of it. The error is saying you are missing a value for NSURLCredential. Try this.

```
    completionHandler(sessionDidReceiveChallenge!(session, challenge),nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public func URLSession(session: URLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: ((URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void)) 
{
    if let serverTrust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust
    {
        completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: serverTrust))
    }
    else 
    { 
        completionHandler(.performDefaultHandling, nil)
    }
}
```

Refer to: https://gist.github.com/VadimDez/ea9106ec7d6cf6eb0e58